# How to remove my picture when I use my gmail account

Tags: gmail

I have a gmail account and whenever I use it to sign up for any site I see my real picture is automatically appear with the sign up !! although in my gmail account I did not setup a picture nor any picture of mine appear there !!

How to remove or prevent my picture to appear whenever I use this gmail account ?

Comment: Do you have any other gmail accounts? Or maybe another account from Hotmail or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it was the gravatar of wordpress.com that link my real photo to my gmail account.